# First child of a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

i would like a background of my very first div but not all first divs of the divs. The very first div does not have class.

I tried the following css but it does not work, it gives background to all first sub-divs too what i do not want :

```
.wrapper div:first-child {background: #ff0000;}
```

or

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {background: #ff0000;}
```

[Fiddle here !](http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/ba5gfr27/7/)

How to give background color only to my very first div without class name ?

Comment: You should use direct child selector `>` like: `.wrapper > div:first-child`

Comment: Whenever i ask a question, someone gives me a minus point and he:she even does not explain... Does someone decided to make my account a hell here or this person finds an amusement in it ???

Comment: Igor, I didn't downvote you but I think the reason you got downvotes is that there are similar questions on this site and this site suggested you with similar question while you were posting this post (_and you might have ignored it_). I know this because I can see the similar questions in the related section in right side of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `>` child selector.

```
.wrapper > div:first-child {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ba5gfr27/8/

Reference: [MDN - Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Comment: yes, this is it ! I will accept your answer, i just want to wait some minutes :) thanks a lot !